# Setting TabBarItem title

Tags: interface-builder, xamarin.ios

I'm using the TabBar for the very first time. I see that I can easily add tabbar items to it. And I see that I can set a icon to it (choosing the identifier). I do so, but when I try to change the title, the identifier -and the icon- go away...

why? Can't I keep predefined icons with custom title text?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The title replaces any image, you can't have image and title on a UIBarButtonItem